# “I was eating two half hamburgers yesterday”

Tags: past-continuous, progressive-aspect, continuous

Yesterday, I was eating half of a hamburger at 3 o’clock, and I was eating half of another hamburger at 6 o’clock.

Why does “I was eating two half hamburgers yesterday” seem weird unlike “I ate two half hamburgers yesterday”?

Comment: There is NO relationship between your choice of tenses and the bizarre point about eating half-hamburgers. It would be the same question if you asked about "I was eating a hamburger yesterday."

Comment: There is no reason to use the continuous tense unless it's to say "I was eating a hamburger when... [something else happened]".

Comment: This is the kind of sentence than ONLY exists on ELL. I have not heard of anyone thinking of a hamburger half once it is halved. It is at that point referred to as a "hamburger" (just a small one), or they make up a new name for it, like a "halfsie" or something.  This is because continually referring to "half a hamburger" is clumsy and unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of tense has absolutely nothing to do with the unusual practice of eating half hamburgers. "Was eating" is in the past progressive tense and is used to describe the past in an ongoing sense. If you're describing something that happened while you were eating the half hamburgers, this tense would be appropriate and would not sound weird - "I was eating two half hamburgers yesterday, when I realized I forgot to buy ketchup."

If you're just describing something that happened in the past with no ongoing sense, you should use the past perfect - "I ate two half hamburgers yesterday". There's nothing else to connect us to the time of when you ate the hamburgers, so using the past perfect puts it firmly in the past. If you follow that with "I realized I forgot to buy ketchup", both statements are firmly in the past, and you lose the connection between the statements by using the past perfect.

This sentence would not be any different if you just described eating one hamburger. The half hamburgers don't change anything about the grammar of this sentence.

Comment: Additionally, *I ate two **half hamburgers*** is a strange usage.  *Half hamburgers*, said that way, is not a traditional usage.  You would be far more likely to say, *I ate **half of** two hamburgers.***

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this sounds weird, because it IS rather weird.

My take on the most natural way of saying this is:

"Yesterday I ate half a hamburger, twice."

Note that I am using the past tense there "ate" which helps, compared to your first example, and making it clearer that I am talking about whole hamburgers. Your second example implies that the hamburger(s?) were cut in half prior to eating.

Answer (score 0):

It is a strange situation, and you shouldn't expect a short phrase. You did two things.

> I ate two half-hamburgers yesterday! I ate half a hamburger at 3 and half of another hamburger at 6.

You'd probably now be pressed into explaining why.

If you are talking about something normal "I ate two apples yesterday" You don't need to explain.  But if it is bizarre you need to tell the full story, or nobody will understand what you are talking about!

One very important fact is to remember that there is another person. When you are talking to someone, always remember that it is a conversation and not a monologue. That means you will be alternately speaking, listening, explaining and responding.