# “Two half apples” and “half two apples”

Tags: grammatical-number

“Two half apples” means “two halves of apples.”

“Half two apples” means “half of apples (=one apple).”

Is it correct?

Comment: Mathematically you're correct.  But "half of two apples" doesn't really have any meaning, because it's not something that would ever be said.  Except perhaps in some rare case where you'd chopped up two apples and then used half of the pile of chopped apple.

Comment: No. You don't use "half" that way. You either have to say "Halve two apples" (telling someone to cut them both in half) or say "He has two apples, each cut in half." Also, language is not math. Don't approach it that way or you will hate it.

Comment: This reminds me of the "half hamburger" questions https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/293999/i-was-eating-two-half-hamburgers-yesterday  And there was a half-apple question as well, but it seems to have been deleted.

Comment: One piece of advice for question writers.  Please, no Minimal Working Example.  In other stacks, questioners are strongly encouraged to simplify their code to show the problem and nothing else.  That doesn't work in the Natural Language stacks. There is no way for a non-native speaker of English to verify the W part of the example.  So we need to see the real problem you have.  And not the example problem about apples.

Comment: You can include the "Apple" problem as a secondary example. But we would benefit greatly by know what the real problem was.  What was the context in which you wanted to refer to (a number) (a fraction) (object)  What was the actual object, fraction and number?

Comment: @James K Apple is an actual object.

Comment: It's an actual object, but is it the actual context in which you were unable to communicate in English.  To whom were you talking about apples and half-apples?

Comment: @James K I won’t talk to someone, but hear from someone.

Comment: If you actually heard these sentences from someone, please give us more context.  Your questions about half apples and half hamburgers do not sound like things native speakers would say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one needs a hyphen (and a corresponding rhythmic device)

> Two half-apples

Except that a "half-apple" isn't a common thing, so this particular constuction is very rare.

You would *never* say "Half of two apples" to mean one apple.  Never, not in natural English.

In fact the only time you will ever have to worry about if you are correct or not is when you are posing grammar problems.  It simply doesn't occur as a natural problem.

So you are not correct.  You should write

> Two half-apples.  (for this rare situation)

> One apple (for the more common situation)

Comment: "Two half-apples" is not the same as "one apple." If I told you that a recipe called for "two half-apples" I would mean that you should use two apple halves in the recipe... which would probably mean you would *keep* them as "whole" half-apples. If I said a recipe called for "one apple" I would imagine you would chop it up somehow.

Comment: What do you mean "you would keep them as "whole" half-apples"? What is a whole half-apple?